# Series 40 application to use Nokia VGA camera

Tags: java, java-me, nokia, series-40

Is it possible for a Series 40 application to use the Nokia VGA camera with Java or Flash lite? I need the application to take a photo every 5 minutes and then upload the JPEG file to a server.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible with JaveME.
Use JSR-135 API to take the picture and then upload it using HTTP.
JSR-135 should be supported in all modern S40 devices.

Note that S40 is a software platform used on a series of Nokia devices. S40 is not Symbian based, there is no such thing as Symbian S40.